# Sitecore 7.2 - Unable to access uploaded media items from content delivery servers

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-media-library

I just upgraded a Sitecore site from version 6.5 to version 7.2.

The site has 1 CMS server and 2 CD servers with standard scalability configuration setting. The CMS server has 3 publishing targets (web_external01 -> CD1, web_external02 -> CD2, staging -> CMS / preview). Media items are stored in database.

After the upgrade, I cannot view the newly upload media items anymore from CD servers after publishing (images, pdfs,etc), but they are displaying properly on the web target.

Scenario :

1. upload a test.png under Media Library -> publish to 3 publishing targets -> browse to http://cms.xxxxx.com/~/media/test.png -> WORKS !
2. browse to http://xxxxx.com/~/media/test.png -> Sitecore Document Not found error

Accessing the existing media items (the items that are already exist before upgrade) works.

Anyone has idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: If you switch to the CD1/CD2 databases in the Sitecore desktop, are the media items there?

Comment: Did you run all the required SQL scripts on the web databases as well?

Comment: Do your have separate web databases for CD1, CD2, Preview? If yes then check again your publishing targets. Try publishing content Item I'll bet it will not work on CD's. Check web config or AppConfig/Includes folder (it may be possible the upgrade to overwrite your config), you can do that via cms.

Comment: @MartinDavies, Yes the media items are in CD1, CD2 publishing targets after switching targets

Comment: @jammykam Yes, There is only one SQL script for upgrading 6.5 to 7.2 rev.140526 (from 6.5 to 6.6)

Comment: @SilentTremor Yeah, I have separate databases for CD1, CD2 and Preview. Editing / Adding contents and publishing to CD1 , CD2 and preview works. Newly created media items work on preview BUT not on CD1 and CD2

Comment: Check the `<sites>` section for CD1/2 (via `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`) and make sure `database` attribute is set correctly to `web_external01` and `web_external02` respectively.

Comment: @uiru Map on CMS config (connection string) one of your CD DB to be used as Web and check if Item is published or you have problem retrieving the Item. You might detect what is wrong on your CD database mapped as WEB DB (navigate with chrome console open) <add name="web" connectionString="user id=user;password=pass;Data Source=your_CD_web_database Web"/>. If Publish is not performing correctly republish all your /sitecore/templates/System. Other suggestion finding the issue... don't know

Comment: is preview target working fine? after publishing or it just working for newly created item?

Comment: How is your History Engine, is it turned on and everything?

Answer (score 0):

This seems that your media item did not get published to your CD servers.

Please check the following:

1. Check if the item is found on your external DB for the CD servers.
2. Scalability setting well setup. For more info about how to setup the scalability setting, you can read my post [Sitecore Scalability Setting Configuration](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/sitecore-scalability-setting/)
3. If you are using CDN, check if the image is available when using the CDN link, if not, do an invalidate CDN on the image path
4. Check your Site definition to see where your site is taking the image, i.e, the media library path